# How to Disable contact between two SKSpriteNodes?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2, collision-detection, skspritenode

For some reason in the code below the Enemy Bacteria moves the Food (peas) when they touch each other. I don't have them coded to test contact with each other. Any help? I'm trying to make it impossible for the two types of sprites to collide.

```
import SpriteKit
var apple=SKSpriteNode()

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var bg=SKSpriteNode()
    var peas=SKSpriteNode()
    var bacteria=SKSpriteNode()
    var bactys_Y=[SKSpriteNode]()
    var bactys_X=[SKSpriteNode]()
    var border=CGRect()
   // var gandolf=SKSpriteNode()
    enum ColliderType:UInt32{
        case Bug=1
        case Food=2
        case Enemy=4
        case Gandolf=8
    }

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        border=CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.height, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height-200)
        //gandolf.physicsBody=SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: border)
        let bactPic=SKTexture(imageNamed: "bacteria.png")
        /* Setup your scene here */
        //bg info
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate=self
        let bg_texture=SKTexture(imageNamed: "wood-texture-pattern.jpg")
        bg=SKSpriteNode(texture: bg_texture)
        bg.position=CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        bg.size.height=self.frame.height
        bg.size.width=self.frame.width
       // self.addChild(bg)
        //bug info
        let applePic=SKTexture(imageNamed:"bug.png")
        apple=SKSpriteNode(texture:applePic)
        apple.position=CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

        print(self.frame.width)
       // let bactPic=SKTexture(imageNamed: "bacteria.png")
        //peas info
        let peas_texture=SKTexture(imageNamed: "peas.png")
        peas=SKSpriteNode(texture: peas_texture)
       // peas.position=CGPointMake(200,300)
        peas.physicsBody=SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: peas_texture.size().width/4)
        apple.physicsBody=SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius:applePic.size().width/2)
        peas.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity=false
        apple.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity=false
        bg.zPosition=1
        apple.zPosition=2
        peas.zPosition=3
        apple.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask=ColliderType.Bug.rawValue
        apple.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask=ColliderType.Food.rawValue
        peas.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask=ColliderType.Food.rawValue
        peas.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask=ColliderType.Bug.rawValue
        bacteria.physicsBody=SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bactPic.size().width*0.06/2)
        bacteria.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask=ColliderType.Enemy.rawValue
        bacteria.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask=ColliderType.Bug.rawValue
     //   gandolf.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask=ColliderType.Gandolf.rawValue
    //    gandolf.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask=ColliderType.Enemy.rawValue
        peas.setScale(0.4)
        apple.setScale(0.5)
        // bacteria info
      //  gandolf.color=UIColor.blackColor()
      //  self.addChild(gandolf)


        self.addChild(apple)
      //  self.addChild(peas)
        _=NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnBacteria"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        spawnBacteria()
        spawnFood()


    }
    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
      //  peas.removeFromParent()
      //  spawnFood()
        let first=contact.bodyA
        let second=contact.bodyB
        if first.categoryBitMask==ColliderType.Bug.rawValue || second.categoryBitMask==ColliderType.Bug.rawValue{
            if first.categoryBitMask==ColliderType.Food.rawValue || second.categoryBitMask==ColliderType.Food.rawValue{
                peas.removeFromParent()
                spawnFood()
            }
        }
        if first.categoryBitMask==ColliderType.Bug.rawValue || second.categoryBitMask==ColliderType.Bug.rawValue{
            if first.categoryBitMask==ColliderType.Enemy.rawValue || second.categoryBitMask==ColliderType.Enemy.rawValue{
                print("DEATH")
            }
        }

    }
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
       /* Called when a touch begins */


    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
       // print("x: "+String(apple.position.x))
       // print("y: "+String(apple.position.y))
        for node:SKSpriteNode in bactys_X{
            if node.position.x<=0{
                print("collide")
                node.physicsBody?.velocity=CGVector(dx:0, dy:0)
                node.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx:6, dy:0))
            }else if node.position.x>=self.frame.size.width-3{
                node.physicsBody?.velocity=CGVector(dx:0,dy:0)
                node.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx:-6,dy:0))
            }
        }
        for node:SKSpriteNode in bactys_Y{
            if node.position.y>=self.frame.size.height-3{
                node.physicsBody?.velocity=CGVector(dx:0,dy:0)
                node.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx:0,dy:-6))
            }else if node.position.y<=200{
                node.physicsBody?.velocity=CGVector(dx:0,dy:0)
                node.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx:0,dy:6))
            }
        }
    }
    func spawnFood(){
        let peas_texture=SKTexture(imageNamed: "peas.png")
        peas=SKSpriteNode(texture: peas_texture)
        peas.physicsBody=SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: peas_texture.size().width/4)
        peas.zPosition=3
        peas.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity=false
        peas.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask=ColliderType.Food.rawValue
        peas.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask=ColliderType.Bug.rawValue
        let x=CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.size.width-40)+20))
        let y=CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.size.height-20-200))+200)
        //print(self.frame.size.width)
        print("height: "+String(self.frame.size.height))
        print("x: "+String(x))
        print("y: "+String(y))
        peas.position=CGPointMake(x,y)
        peas.setScale(0.4)
        self.addChild(peas)
    }
    func spawnBacteria(){
        let bactPic=SKTexture(imageNamed: "bacteria.png")
        bacteria=SKSpriteNode(texture: bactPic)
        bacteria.physicsBody=SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bactPic.size().width*0.06/2)
        bacteria.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity=false
        bacteria.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask=ColliderType.Enemy.rawValue
        bacteria.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask=ColliderType.Bug.rawValue
       // bacteria.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask=ColliderType.Gandolf.rawValue
        bacteria.zPosition=4
        let x=CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.size.width-40)+20))
        let y=CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.size.height-20-200))+200)
        bacteria.position=CGPointMake(x,y)
        bacteria.setScale(0.06)
        let decide=Int(arc4random_uniform(3))

        self.addChild(bacteria)
        if decide==0{
            //move left
           //  let move=SKAction.moveByX(-6, y: 0, duration: 0.1)
            // let start=SKAction.repeatActionForever(move)
             //bacteria.runAction(start)
            bacteria.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -6,dy: 0))
            bactys_X.append(bacteria)

        }else if decide==1{
            //move right
          //  let move=SKAction.moveByX(6, y: 0, duration: 0.1)
            // let start=SKAction.repeatActionForever(move)
            // bacteria.runAction(start)
            bacteria.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 6, dy: 0))
            bactys_X.append(bacteria)
        }else if decide==2{
            //move up
          //  let move=SKAction.moveByX(0, y: 6, duration: 0.1)
            // let start=SKAction.repeatActionForever(move)
            //  bacteria.runAction(start)
            bacteria.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 6))
            bactys_Y.append(bacteria)
        }else{
            //move down
           //  let move=SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -6, duration: 0.1)
            // let start=SKAction.repeatActionForever(move)
          //  bacteria.runAction(start)
            bacteria.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0,dy: -6))
            bactys_Y.append(bacteria)
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the collision bit mask of a physics body is set to 0xFFFFFFFF (interact with all objects) and its dynamic property set to true. Looking at your code it seems like your haven't set them hence its using the default values.

You will have to set these properties to achieve your desired result

```
...physicsBody.dynamic = false
...physicsBody.collisionBitMask = //set to something
```

Comment: My pleasure, happy coding